# React - how to show propup based on API-result?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have built an axios call that returns a Promise which holds a promiseResult with an array.
Now I want to show a popup based on if the array is empty or not.

this is my code:

```js
    createPopup = () => {
        const { myUser } = this.props;
        const { showPopup } = this.state;

        MyAxiosCall.fetchGetArray(myUser.id)
            .then((data) => {
                if (data.length < 1) { this.setState({ showPopup: true }) }
                if (data.length > 0) { this.setState({ showPopup: false }) }
            });

        if (!showPopup) {
            return;
        }
        if (showPopup) {

            return <Popup/>
        }
        }
```

Right now I am using a bool(ShowPopup that is set to false) to show or hide the popup. My problem is that when I debug the createPopup function it loops the createpopupfunction and always seem to start as false, but it gets the right state the second time it loops thru the function.

How do I get the function to stop looping?
And how can I get the function to wait for the statechange based from the response from my api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while since i used react with classes.

in functional components you can simply use `useEffect`.

in this case setting `showPopup` as an attribute for `<PopUp />` and managing visibility from inside `<PopUp />` probably would solve you problem

Answer (score 0):

It’s a lifecycle issue. Convert to a functional component and this should fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is happening because your conditions for popup are outside the `then()` block.

So what's happening is for the first time promise is in `pending` state and during this your state is unchanged because you are updating the state in `then` block. As soon as promise gets fullfilled your state changes and you are getting correct state in second go.

Try using async await so that js will wait until your api call is complete and then it will execute the conditions.